# d3.js TSV to Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, d3.js, csv

I'm working on a graph with d3.js library.
The 3d.js tsv parser creates the 'd' variable as such:

TSV:

```
day Value
01-01   50
01-02   45
01-03   60
```

code:

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data){...}
```

and now you use 'd.day' and 'd.Value' to build your graph - scaterplots, linegraph, etc...

I won't be using a tsv file but a javascript variable instead. Which is the most correct (if possible) javascript variable representation in order to use this d.day and d.Value in 3d.js and parsing it conventionally like 'svg.data(data)'?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not reading from a file, you can still use the JSON format (which is what you're talking about). The format for a json variable is as follows:

```
var myVariable = {
"indexA" : "valueA",
"indexB" : "valueB"
}
```

You can even have an array as the value (even though you didn't ask) and that would look very similar:

```
var myVariable = {
"indexA" : [ "indexA1": "valueA1", "indexA2": "valueA2", ...],
"indexB" : "valueB"
}
```

You can find out more information about the JSON format here: http://www.json.org/