# Importing data into d3.js from javascript variables

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, d3.js

tl;dr How do I import d3.js data directly from other javascript vars instead of from a file?

Long version:

This question was asked in two other places [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231357/how-to-read-in-data-into-d3-js-from-multiple-javascript-arrays-and-dynamically) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828101/d3-js-tsv-to-javascript-variable), but the answers were rather... lackluster, so I thought I'd ask the question a bit more specifically.

I am trying to create a chart with d3.js for the first time, but I need to load the data in from other javascript variables (arrays, specifically), not from an external file like below. I'm using javascript inside of a rails 4 app.

I want to convert this:

```
    d3.csv("sp500.csv", type, function(error, data) {
    x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; })));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; }))]);
    x2.domain(x.domain());
    y2.domain(y.domain());

    focus.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("d", area);

    focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    context.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("d", area2);

    context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
        .call(xAxis2);

    context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x brush")
        .call(brush)
      .selectAll("rect")
        .attr("y", -6)
        .attr("height", height2 + 7);
  });
```

into something that loads the data directly from a javascript variable I have already set, something like this:

```
    var data = [];
    for (i = 0; i < Math.round(totaltime / interval); i++)
    {
      data[i] = {
        "x": i,
        "y": reactionratebyinterval[i]
      };
    }
```

But all of my attempts keep failing, as I don't think I'm quite understanding what exactly changes when you aren't importing from a file. And every example I can find is one of only two types - either the data is directly entered into the graph in the code, such as:

```
var lineData = [{
  'x': 1,
  'y': 5
}, {
  'x': 20,
  'y': 20
}, {
  'x': 40,
  'y': 10
}, {
  'x': 60,
  'y': 40
}, {
  'x': 80,
  'y': 5
}, {
  'x': 100,
  'y': 60
}];
```

Or it uses the code I had above, where it imports it from a file of some sort. I need to import it from other variables though, that may change in size and content at any time. How would I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d3.csv` is only used for that you need to populate the data when data had been loaded, so it provide a callback function to handle this.

but in your situation, you don't need that callback at all.

what you only need to do is call `d3.append` function and introduce your data like this:

```
someSVG.selectAll(".element-class")
    .data(your_data_variable)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .classed("range-circle-inner", true)
    .attr({
      // here: d is element in your data array
      "cx": function(d) {
        return d.x;
      },
      "cy": op.top,
      "r": function(d, i){
        return d.y;
      },
      "fill": "#4499ee"
    });
```

hope to help you :)

Comment: That definitely gave me a good starting ground, thanks! My chart is a line chart, any chance you can clarify it for that?
It will have a date for the Y axis, and a whole number for the X axis, if that helps.  My code to fill the data was:

        `var lineData = [];
        for (i = 0; i < Math.round(totaltime / interval); i++)
        {
          lineData[i] = {
            "x": Date.now() - i * 3600,
            "y": reactionratebyinterval[i]
          };
        }`

Comment: I just make a demo for you, you  can change lineData with your owns, and check the result. :)  http://jsfiddle.net/reg027/4jpmbL88/